# Using command line to remove lines from text file

Tags: perl, shell, command-line, command

I have a text file and need to remove all lines that DO NOT contain `http` in them.  Alternatively, it could just output all the files that DO contain `http` in them to the new file.

The name of my original file is list.txt and I need to generate a new file with a name like new.txt

I know that there are several ways to do this via command line, but what I'm really looking for is the quickest way since I need to do this with several files and each of them are a few gigs in size...

Comment: this can be done with `sed` or `awk` or `grep` and negation operator, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11217/sed-one-liner-to-delete-any-line-that-does-not-contain-lowercase-letters ; is quickly really required? will this be a normal operation, or a use-once-and-forget task?

Comment: Please note that as you are removing text from the middle of the file you will need to rewrite the file with any tool, so it is going to be slow (1GB -> 100 seconds if your drive can sustain 10MB/s, which it probably won't be able to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest, shortest solution,

```
fgrep -v "http"
```

Of course, grep, egrep, awk, perl, etc make this more fungible.

Here is a short shell script.  Edit "delhttp.sh" containing,

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
    fgrep -v "http"
elif [ $# -eq 1 ] ; then
    f1=${1:-"null"}
    if [ ! -f $f1 ]; then echo "file $f1 dne"; exit 1; fi
    fgrep -v "http" $f1 #> $f2
elif [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
    f1=${1:-"null"}
    if [ ! -f $f1 ]; then echo "file $f1 dne"; exit 1; fi
    f2=${2:-"null"}
    fgrep -v "http" $f1 > $f2
fi
```

Then make this file executable using,

```
chmod +x delhttp.sh
```

Here is a perl script (if you prefer), Edit "delhttp.pl" containing,

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $f1=$ARGV[0]||"-";
my $f2=$ARGV[1]||"-";
my ($fh, $ofh);
open($fh,"<$f1") or die "file $f1 failed";
open($ofh,">$f2") or die "file $f2 failed";
while(<$fh>) { if( !($_ =~ /http/) ) { print $ofh "$_"; } }
```

Again, make this file executable using,

```
chmod +x delhttp.pl
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -i -lne 'print if(/http/)' your_file
```

This above command will delete all the lines from the file if they do not have http.
If you insist on keeping the original file backup, the you can anyhow give and option of ".bak" like mentioned below:

```
perl -i.bak -lne 'print if(/http/)' your_file
```

By this your_file.bak will be generated which is nothing but a copy of the original file and original file will be modified according to your need.
Also you can use awk:

```
awk '/http/' your_file
```

This will out put to the console. You can anyhow use '>' to store the output in a new file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use grep. Using `-v` inverts the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

```
grep -v 'http' list.txt
```

Using Perl one-liner:

```
perl -ne '/^(?:(?!http).)*$/ and print' list.txt > new.txt
```